# Add image using cURL

Tags: 7, external-scripts

I'm migrating data from Zoho creator into Drupal 7. I wrote a PHP script to get all records and save them into nodes and that worked fine, but I need help to get the images and add them to the nodes as well. This is the code I have to get the image using CURL.

```php
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url . $id . "/Image1/download",
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken $token")
));
$image = curl_exec($curl);
```

What should I do after that?

Comment: You can use file_save_data to save the file data to a local managed file, then set the resulting file id as target_id on the image field item for the node.

Comment: If you are using the Migrate Framework in 7 this should be a breeze.

Comment: Aswered on StackOverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65533807/add-an-image-to-drupal-7-using-curl